# How can I disable back button on Logitech G5?

Tags: windows, logitech-mouse

When browsing the internet or playing browser games i always accidentally hit the button near my thumb on my G5 mouse. This button causes the browser to go back a page every time its pressed and can be very annoying. Uberoptions and SetPoint is too much to depend on for something so little, I'm sure there is something easier I can do?

Comment: Are you sure you are holding the mouse right? If so your thumb should be below the buttons and holding it in a way that your fingers can't slip to the button on accident.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The button you are referring to is Mouse4 (referred to as XButton1 by AHK) which enables backward navigation on mice. I had the same problem, I just added another line to my massive [AutoHotkey](http://autohotkey.com) script:

```
XButton1::return
```

will do the trick. XButton is actually derived from Windows mouse input dating back to Windows 2000 when Microsoft supported the five-button Microsoft IntelliMouse Explorer. More on it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645601%28VS.85%29.aspx#_win32_XBUTTONs).

Comment: Ahhh, AHK- the answer to all of life's difficulties. Do you know of a script to make coffee and bring it to me?
+1

Comment: Given the correct outputs, I think AHK probably *could* make and bring you a cup of coffee :P I love autohotkey

Answer (score 3):

To be fair, it's a useful function. Thusly, I'd do this

```
XButton1:: 
If (A_PriorHotKey = A_ThisHotKey and A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < 500)
  {
    Send {XButton1}
  }
return
```

Which will press the key on a double-press, but not a single.
(and it stacks from there, a triple press still registers as being another click, so this way you don't lose any functionality, just have to press the key an additional time)

Answer (score 0):

Control Panel > Mouse

There should be a buttons tab where you can set the actions that each button does. I've never used Logitech mice but my Microsoft Sidewinder mouse has options to disable and rebind any mouse key.